# How to access to the microphone in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, api, microphone

The webcam is supported already in Opera Next, but what about microphone support? Do you know something about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that there is a spec located here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html

And that webkit supports it like this: http://www.labnol.org/software/add-speech-recognition-to-website/19989/

The correct code would be:

```
<input x-webkit-speech type="text" />
```

Comment: Not the speech input. I mean a real microphone API, using we can create applications like skype in browser, without plugins like flash.

Comment: @Danny Fox: why not the speech input? If you're wanting to capture audio, a speech input sounds ideal. Why does this not fit what you need?

Comment: @JonCram - I came here looking to write a ukulele tuner.  Speech input won't help me even a little.  I need an audio stream from the microphone.